# Very slow loop through rows to copy/paste values

Tags: excel, vba

I need to calculate a large list of different iterations of three variables within an Excel formula. I do not believe "What-If" analysis can be used due to there being three variables.

I have written the below to try to "copy/paste" the three variables from a variable sheet "Batch" into another calculation sheet (Main). After this calculation has taken place within the sheet I select the result from the calculation sheet (Main) and paste this back into the original "batch" sheet.

This is incredibly slow. Estimated around 18 hours on my machine based on single iteration times.

```vb
Sub Macro3()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To 65095
        Application.StatusBar = "Current iteration: " & i
        'CopyPaste Data
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("D6").Value = Worksheets("Batch").Range("D" & i).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("D7").Value = Worksheets("Batch").Range("E" & i).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("D8").Value = Worksheets("Batch").Range("F" & i).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("D9").Value = Worksheets("Batch").Range("G" & i).Value
        'CopyPaste Result
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Batch").Range("H" & i).Value = Worksheets("Main").Range("E19")
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried turning off automatic calculations when you start? With a large file, with many calculations, that can definitely slow you down... `application.calculation = xlmanual // = xlautomatic` can be used at start/end of code, whereas you would want to complete all of the calculations at a single time, rather than currently happening for the sheet after each line is value=value

Comment: An alternative approach is to have the calculation performed in VBA which currently happens on your calculation page and have that printed to the results page.

Comment: Hi @Cyril thanks for getting back to me - Unfortunately the Automatic Calculations are required to be completed within the worksheet and it is not an option to complete them within VBA. The VBA here is effectively to try to automate this rather than manually trying c65k permutations of the system.

Comment: @Chrisb1712 then let's try and get you a situation where you have calculations occur once per iteration of your loop.  Posted an answer with an update for `Application.Transpose()` and toggling calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of using `Application.Transpose()` to support one instance of values being input, triggering calculations once:

```
Sub testApplicationTranspose()
    With Sheets(1)
        Dim sourceRng As Range:  Set sourceRng = .Range("b2:b5")
        Dim destinationRng As Range:  Set destinationRng = .Range("d7:g7")
    End With
    destinationRng = Application.Transpose(sourceRng)
End Sub
```

[image]

---

Edit1:  Applying to your code:

```
Sub Execute()
    applicationToggle False
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 65095
        Application.StatusBar = "Current iteration: " & i
        'CopyPaste Data
        Dim sourceRng As Range:  Set sourceRng = Worksheets("Batch").Range("D" & i & ":G" & i)
        Dim destinationRng As Range:  Set destinationRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("D6:D9")
        destinationRng = Application.Transpose(sourceRng)
        'CopyPaste Result
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Batch").Range("H" & i).Value = Worksheets("Main").Range("E19")
    Next i
    applicationToggle True
End Sub

Sub applicationToggle(val as Boolean)
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = val
        .ScreenUpdating = val
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Turning off calculation just for that one line does not make much sense because `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` will trigger a calculation too if the line before would. So you don't win anything here.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ will remove then; was under the impression it affects the next line.  thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Many Thanks @cyril, will give this ago - I hadn't considered that this would result in 3 worksheet calculations when transferring across data - Good spot.

Comment: @Cyril - This is much more performant - many thanks for all of your time on this. (Main bottleneck now is solely the c24k polynomials being solved in Main sheet - Can't win them all)